# Mongoose create - creating object containing other object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two models: `Document` and `URL`:

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  path: String,
  urls: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'URL' }],
});

const URLSchema = new Schema({
  url: String,
  display_url: String,
  ref: Boolean,
});
```

I want to create multiple documents from an array so what I do is:

```
const documents = [{ ..., urls: [ ... ] }, ...];

Document.create(documents, (err, docs) => {
    ...
});
```

But then I get the error `urls: Cast to Array failed for value`. I guess that this is because I want to add urls but I have not yet added them to the database (so I have no ID).

Is there a way to create a Schema so I can add them without creating the URLs first? (so they will be added automagically?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pre` document middleware to implement `cascade` on `save`. You can see in the output on save of `Document` the `URL`s also saved to collection

[mongoose middleware documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    path: String,
    urls: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'URL' }],
  });

  const URLSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    display_url: String,
    ref: Boolean,
  });

  const URL = mongoose.model('URL', URLSchema, 'urls');

  DocumentSchema.pre('save', function(next){
      URL.insertMany(this.urls, function(err, res){
          if(err) throw err;
          next();
      })
  });

  const Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema, 'documents');

  var u1 = new URL({url : 'www.google.com'});
  var d = new Document({text: 'test text', urls : [u1]})

  d.save(function(err, doc){
      console.log(doc)
  })
```

output

```
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$ node so2.js
`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Mongoose: urls.insertMany([ { __v: 0, _id: 5a5b345f98f048281d88eac1, url: 'www.google.com' } ], {})
Mongoose: documents.insert({ text: 'test text', _id: ObjectId("5a5b345f98f048281d88eac2"), urls: [ ObjectId("5a5b345f98f048281d88eac1") ], __v: 0 })
{ __v: 0,
  text: 'test text',
  _id: 5a5b345f98f048281d88eac2,
  urls: [ { url: 'www.google.com', _id: 5a5b345f98f048281d88eac1 } ] }
^C
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$
```